Magento2.4.6 Install in Windows 10 using XAMPP
I am trying to install Magento 2.4.6 on Windows10 using XAMPP I have almost completed the setup for the magento2 and when I run the installation command it throws like Unable to apply data patch Magento\Theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes for module Magento_Theme. Original exception message: Wrong file [PFA] If anyone knows how to fix this please help me fix this, I tried browsing and still can't able to find the correct one.
Thanks in Advance



